# Alternatives to TrueCrypt

Tags: security, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a tool to encrypt a file or directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27770/is-there-a-tool-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory)

Hello.

Are there any alternatives to TrueCrypt that work out of the box and don't require any installation? I am looking for something built right into Linux that I use to protect my data. Encrypting the partition is also a good idea.

What should I be looking at?

Comment: And for encrypting partitions: [How to make a partition truly secure?](http://askubuntu.com/q/43206/6969)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any other encryption programs that will work without a download and installation, you could try LUKS, 
http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/, it is an alternative to Trucrypt that is made to work well with Linux operating systems, but it needs to downloaded and installed, however, you most likely could install it to a small USB flashdrive and always run it from that......