# How do I encrypt ext4 home folder partition?

Tags: home-directory, data-recovery, ext4, encrypted-partition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I encrypt my home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081/how-do-i-encrypt-my-home-partition)

**EDIT: Its not a duplicate. "[How do I encrypt my home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081/how-do-i-encrypt-my-home-partition)" is old and does not mention anything about EXT4.**

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04.

At the time of installation I did not encrypted my home partition, but now I feel the need of it. How do I encrypt my home partition?

Please note, I have ext4 file system.

Once encrypted will I be able to recover my data in case of OS Crash (which occures very rarely)?

Comment: Could you create a new question for the recovery question?

Comment: Encrypting a partition is done with LUKS, encrypting a home directory is not the same as encrypting the partition. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/27828/is-encrypting-the-home-directory-on-an-encrypted-lvm-installation-overkill/34897#34897